# Number formatting after mapping?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, replace

I have a data frame with a number column, such as:

```
CompteNum
100
200
300
400
500
```

and a file with the mapping of all these numbers to other numbers, that I import to python and convert into a dictionary:

```
{100: 1; 200:2; 300:3; 400:4; 500:5}
```

And I am creating a second column in the data frame that combine both numbers in the format df number + dict number: From 100 to 1001 and so on...

```
## dictionary
accounts = pd.read_excel("mapping-accounts.xlsx")
accounts = accounts[['G/L Account #','FrMap']] 
accounts = accounts.set_index('G/L Account #').to_dict()['FrMap']
## data frame --> CompteNum is the Number Column
df['CompteNum'] = df['CompteNum'].map(accounts1).astype(str) + df['CompteNum'].astype(str)
```

The problem is that my output then is 100.01.0 instead of 1001 and that creates additional manual work in the output excel file. I have tried:

```
df['CompteNum'] = df['CompteNum'].str.replace('.0', '')
```

but it doesn't deletes ALL the zero's, and I would want the additional ones deleted. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is problem missing values for non matched values after `map`, possible solution is:

```
print (df)
   CompteNum
0        100
1        200
2        300
3        400
4        500
5         40

accounts1  = {100: 1, 200:2, 300:3, 400:4, 500:5}

s = df['CompteNum'].astype(str)
s1 = df['CompteNum'].map(accounts1).dropna().astype(int).astype(str)
df['CompteNum'] = (s + s1).fillna(s)
print (df)
  CompteNum
0      1001
1      2002
2      3003
3      4004
4      5005
5        40
```

Your solution should be changed for replace by regex - `$` for end of string with escape `.`, because special regex character (regex any char):

```
df['CompteNum'] = df['CompteNum'].str.replace('\.0$', '')
```